# Circle ImageView in the center of layout

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, geometry

Sorry for my english. I want to create a circle `ImageView` and i use this [library](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) all is well, but i can't locate this image in the center of my layout. I create to display in all screen Resolutions, and i use `layout_weight` if use `layout_weight` I can not put a static size image.

Bellow is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/p_img"
        android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result of this code:

[image]

**UPD:**
my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/p_edit_proofile"
                    android:id="@+id/editProfile"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        >

                        <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/p_img"
                            android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
                            android:layout_centAerInParent="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>



                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/nameProfile"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/status" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="test"
                        android:textColor="#4fcc54"
                        android:id="@+id/aided" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:text="PIN"
                            android:id="@+id/pin"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                            android:src="@mipmap/p_key"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/key" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
 <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/p_img"
                        android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

This will center the image in your **RelativeLayout**

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `layout_centerInParent` not work. Still same

Comment: i believe your RelativeLayout is not root view so use layout_centerInParent on relativeLayout too.

Comment: I update my answer. I use in root layout `layout_centerInParent` but its not work

Answer (score 1):

In your nested `RelativeLayout` remove `android:layout_weight` and add `android:layout_gravity = "center"`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but if i remove `android:layout_weight` my layout where is image It occupies the entire space

Comment: Just try it with `gravity` then.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use   `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_weight="0.3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

android:layout_centerInParent="true"

in the CircularImageView

Regards